# Testing Spring-data-rest one-to-many mappings with RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-data-rest, resttemplate

I have a Spring Boot application exposing REST API using Spring-data-rest. Some of my entities have OneToMany mappings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "records")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Record {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "unique_record_id")
  private long id;

  ...

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinTable(name = "cycles_records", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "unique_record_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "unique_cycle_id"))
  private Cycle cycle;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cycles", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "user_id", "cycle_id" }))
@Getter
@Setter
public class Cycle {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "unique_cycle_id")
  private long id;

  ...

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "cycles_records", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "unique_cycle_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "unique_record_id"))
  private List<Record> records;
}
```

Both entities have corresponding repositories.

When POSTing new record to a collection belonging to a cycle, I can simply send the following request to `/records`:

```
{
  ...record parameters
  "cycle": "/cycles/1"
}
```

This will create a new entity and add it to a corresponding cycle. I am now trying to test this behavior in my itnegration test and I wonder whether there is easy way how to do this using objects rather then manually creating the body of the request in String:

```
@Test
public void test() {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);

    // Record record = new Record();
    // set record parameter here
    // how to set the Cycle URI using objects???

    // this feels clumsy
    String record = "{\n ...parameters...,\n    \"cycle\":\"/cycles/1\"\n}";

    final ResponseEntity<Record> response = testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/records",
        new HttpEntity<>(record, headers), Record.class);

    assertThat(response.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.CREATED));
}
```

Is there some way how to prepare the Record entity as Object and pass it to RestTemplate so it contains the link to the desired Cycle entity or do I have to prepare it in String?

I hope my question makes sense, feel free to clarify if not.